# MS Release Management: sequence of actions for tags only executing first action

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

I'm using Release Management vNext releases.

When I add a sequence of more than one PS\DSC actions under a tag only the first one gets executed. It's like those other actions were ignored. Has this happened to anyone before? Am I missing something?

I can always find a work around, using one tag for each action, combining the scripts... but it just doesn't feel right. I think it should work that way.

Thanks,
HG.

EDIT:
A screenshot of the sequence after the deployment:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F994B409717A5F9D!2228&authkey=!AGrF9BA6dHCUe4w&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

And the deployment log with the error: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F994B409717A5F9D!2229&authkey=!AJnyClHa2RQrv7M&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

Comment: When you open the release, and click on the view sequence tab do see the tags expanded to multiple actions or not?

Comment: Yep, they're there. But, while the fields in executed actions are greyed-out these are still white and editable (in a deployment that's already finished).

Comment: can you paste screenshots of the release definition, and release sequence, and the problem that you are seeing?

Comment: Just edited the post with a link o a screenshot of what I'm seeing. Let me know if I'm missing anything else. Thanks a lot for taking this time to help!

Comment: Is this happening for every release from that RD, happened for a single release or happening for all RDs? Because this seems to be working fine for me. What version of RM are you using?

Comment: I'm using Update 4, and it happens in every release. I don't know, it seems to be some dodgy behavior, may need to restart RM or something. In the mean time I've joined both installation scripts. So I've got it working for the moment. Unless someone has another idea, I'll get back to this when I have some more time and let you know if I find a solution.